# How to reorganize this data?

Tags: python, oop

I have the following input:

- A horizon: number of periods
- A set of *resources*, each resource has an *id* and an *availability* encoded using an array. (e.g [3, 4,..] means 3 units of the resource during the first period, 4 during the second period etc.) The number of elements of the array is equal to the number of periods (i.e the horizon)
- A set of *comms*, each order has a *release date*, *due date* and a set of *tasks*.
  The tasks of an order cannot start before the release date of that order and cannot end after its due date. (My algorithm will fix the starting time of tasks, it's not an input data but accessing the release dates and due dates is important in order to correctly determine the starting time of tasks)
- Each task has a *duration*, *successors*(i.e a set of tasks that cannot start before the task on hand), *resource requirements* (e.g [0,1,3,...] means the task needs 0 units of the first resource, 1 unit of the second resource etc).

Here's how I organized the code:

```
class Problem:
    def __init__(self, horizon, comms, resources):
        self.horizon = horizon
        self.resources = resources 
        self.comms = comms
```

```
    class Resource:
        def __init__(self, identifier, inter):
            self.id = identifier
            self.inter = availabilities
```

```
class Comm:
    def __init__(self, id:str, r_date, d_date, ta):
        self.id = id
        self.r_date = r_date
        self.d_date = d_date
        self.ta = ta
```

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, id:str, dur, succ, requ):
        self.id = id
        self.dur = dur
        self.succ = succ
        self.requ = requ
```

A lot of problems appears using this way of organizing data (e.g. if I need to access data about a task, I need to go through comms to determine to which order it belongs and then accessing the due date, release date for that order). The data is very "nested".

I thought of defining the `Task` object as following but there is a redundancy (information present in both `Task` and `Order`).

```
class Task:
    def __init__(self, id:str, dur, succ, requ, 
                 order_id:str, r_date, d_date):
        self.id = id
        self.dur = dur
        self.succs = succ
        self.requ = requ
        self.order_id = order_id
        self.r_date = r_date
        self.d_date = d_date
```

Some other questions:

For the `successors` is it better to just put the ids of the tasks or the entire objects?

For the resource `requirements`. Assume a task has a requirement [0,1,3,...] of 1 units of the second resource, then I need in someway relate to the appropriate resource id in order to check its availability. How to do it?

Comment: It instead of using `order_id` inside `Task` you have `order`, then instead of having to somehow look up the order from its id, you just access it directly as `task.order` and then you can still get `task.order.id` if you want. I don't know which of `task` and `order` you would create first, but you could allow `task.order` or `order.tasks` to be `None` in whichever one is populated second.

Comment: As regards `release_date` and `due_date`, I guess what to do depends on whether these are separate per task within an order or if they are all the same. If they are all the same, then just have it as a property of the order, and then from the task, access via `task.order.release_date` etc.

Comment: Inside `Order`, you probably want an `add_task` method which will do something like `task=Task(order=self, ....); self.tasks.append(task); return task`

Comment: @alaniwi Is this type of two-ways dependencies (having `order` as an attribute in a `Task` object and having `tasks` in an `Order` object) dangerous?

Comment: I think you need to decide which one can exist without the other. Because it is many to one mapping, I think it should be permissible for order to have empty task list, but a task must always have an order. I think it should be okay provided that the only way that you create tasks is to call `order.create_task`, and that the only way that you destroy tasks is also to call some similar `order.remove_task` method, which removes it from the task list... (more to follow...)

Comment: This is getting too restrictive to write in comments. I'm going to add an answer....

Comment: @alaniwi Okay thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not a complete answer to everything you asked, but was getting too restrictive to put inside the comments.

My idea was something like this, so that you handle the many-to-one mapping between tasks and orders while providing references in both directions, by using `order.add_task` and `order.remove_task` as the way to create and destroy tasks.

It also includes some sanity checking so that the actual order reference inside a task is stored in private variable `_order` but is accessed via the getter property `order`, and this includes sanity checking so that if you hang onto a reference to a task after you have already removed it from its order, then it will raise an exception.

```
class Order:

    def __init__(self, ....):
        ...
        self.tasks = []
        ...

    def add_task(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        add a task to this order (should be called with the arguments that 
        Task.__init__ requires, except for 'order' itself)
        """
        task = Task(order=self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.tasks.append(task)
        return task

    def has_task(self, task):
        return task in self.tasks

    def remove_task(self, task):
        """
        Remove task from this order.  After calling this, 
        the task is orphaned and the reference to the task 
        should be discarded.
        """
        self.tasks.remove(task)


class Task:
    def __init__(self, order:Order, ...):
        ...
        self._order = order
        ...

    @property
    def order(self):
        """
        Getter for self._order with sanity checking that 
        the task is not orphaned.
        """
        if not self._order.has_task(self):
            raise ValueError("orphaned task")
        return self._order
```

So basically, having done that, you do *not* duplicate any other information inside `Task`, e.g. for release date you access via `task.order.release_date` (task should not have a `release_date` property directly) because you have the reference to the order object.  The only duplication is the two-way cross-referencing between tasks and orders.

Comment: Thanks for this detailed answer. I got an idea of how I should think about it. Another question, how to encode the resource `requirements` information ? Assume a task has a requirement [0,1,3,...]. Here it needs 1 units of the second resource, then I need in someway relate to the appropriate resource id in order to check its availability. How to do it more properly than using the list [0,1,3..] ?

Comment: @PatrickK. Maybe a dictionary, key is resource (or resource id), value is amount...

Comment: Assume `requirement` is a dict. For example {"R001": 1, "R005":3} says that a task needs 1 unit of *R001* and 3 units of resource *R005*. The problem is that to access the resource availability I need to go through the list of resources (in the `Problem` object) and look for the one that has the given id.

Comment: @alaniwi, If I have another class Problem that has both a list of tasks and a list of orders as attributes, is it considered to be as a redundancy ? I am asking this question since each task has to order to which it belongs as an attribute and conversely the order has its tasks as an attribute. Would you take a l look here https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/246201/is-there-a-redundancy-with-my-two-ways-associated-objects for more details ?